# Makefile : contains string

Tags: string, makefile, conditional-statements

A variable returns `MINGW32_NT-5.1` or `CYGWIN_NT-5.1.` (yea, dot at the end)

Need to compare that given var contains `NT-5.1` positioned anywhere.

Using cygwin and would like to be compatible with pretty much any *nix.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

The [findstring](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) function is what your heart desires:

> ```
> $(findstring find,in)
> ```
>
> Searches *in* for an occurrence of *find*. If it occurs, the value is *find*; otherwise, the value is empty. You can use this function in a conditional to test for the presence of a specific substring in a given string. Thus, the two examples,
>
> ```
> $(findstring a,a b c)
> $(findstring a,b c)
> ```
>
> produce the values `"a"` and `""` (the empty string), respectively. See [Testing Flags](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Testing-Flags), for a practical application of `findstring`.

Something like:

```
ifneq (,$(findstring NT-5.1,$(VARIABLE)))
    # Found
else
    # Not found
endif
```

> What is the comma here for `ifneq (,$(...`?

Parse it as `ifneq(A,B)` where *A* is the empty string and *B* is `$(findstring...)`. It looks odd because you don't quote strings in Makefiles.

Comment: Is `findstring` case sensitive? If so, is there a simple way to do case insensitive matching?  The manual wasn't clear...

Comment: @IsaacTurner: Yes, `make` functions are _invariably_ case-_sensitive_. Sadly, there are no case-insensitive variants, but as a workaround you could use the `$(shell ...)` function to use a shell command for case conversion - clunky, but it works; e.g.: `$(findstring $(shell echo 'BC' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'), 'abcd')`. If you don't mind specifying `SHELL := bash` to have `make` use bash as the shell, you can take advantage of `shopt -s nocasematch` and perform entire comparisons case-insensitively inside a single `$(shell ...)` call.

Comment: Shouldn't the `if` and `else` be reversed in you example? As I understand it, if findstring returns an empty string, the value was not found.

Comment: @szx Notice that this has `ifneq` rather than `ifeq`. If `findstring` does *not* return an empty string, then it found something. That's how I read it.

Answer (score 24):

```
VARIABLE=NT-5.1_Can_be_any_string
ifeq ($(findstring NT-5.1,$(VARIABLE)),NT-5.1)
    # Found
    RESULT=found
else
    # Not found
    RESULT=notfound
endif

all:
    @echo "RESULT=${RESULT} , output=$(findstring NT-5.1,$(VARIABLE))"
```

It matches the given string and returns

Comment: @JavidJamae It's may be more readable but you are repeating "NT-5.1"