# Why is gcc compiler flag unknown?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-errors, compiler-flags

Been trying to add this flag: `-Wshadow=compatible-local` *([documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wshadow_003dcompatible-local))* when compiling but it just keeps throwing this message:

---

```
`error: unknown warning option '-Wshadow=compatible-local';
 did you mean '-Wshadow- uncaptured-local'?
 [-Werror,-Wunknown-warning-option]`
```

---

Snippet of my makefile:

```
# COMPILER & FLAGS ============================================================

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -std=c11 -O3 \
         -Wall -Wextra -Werror \
         -Wshadow -Wshadow=compatible-local \
         -Wno-sign-compare \
         -fsanitize=integer \
         -fsanitize=undefined \
         -fsanitize=address -fsanitize-address-use-after-scope
```

---

**Updated:**

*Note: my compiler version is `clang-900.0.39.2`. (It says `clang` even though you type in `gcc`, because I'm using macOS and well ... @Aconcagua explains why down below)*

---

Someone know why this is happening ? and/or how to fix it ?

Comment: I believe those are two different flags, in the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wshadow_003dcompatible-local) there are different paragraphs for them. So yeah one for `-Wshadow` and a second for `-Wshadow=compatible-local`... if I'm doing it wrong please correct me.

Comment: What gcc version? Maybe your version is too old to support that flag.

Comment: `Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)`

Comment: That's not gcc. That's clang.

Comment: True lol but... i did `gcc -v` and that's all it gave me. Besides isn't that a version that should run the flag ? Even when using clang as the compiler it gives me that error msg "/

Comment: probably a compatibility link/alias

Comment: Ok @Jean-François Fabre qu'elle est donc la solution ? (i.e So what needs to be done ?)

Comment: Some time ago, GCC was the default compiler on MacOS, then Apple decided to switch to clang as default. Suppose they linked GCC to clang to avoid people wondering why the compiler disappeared (well, more reasonable: not to break any build systems...). Good idea? At least leading to confusion where incompatibilities come into play...

Comment: *"How to fix?"* Install a true GCC on your system, replacing the symlink to clang - or go on with clang but drop the flag that apparently is GCC-specific and not supported by clang (or the clang version *you* are using, if clang added the flag later, you could upgrade it).

Comment: @Aconcagua hey this is actually it, exactly what you said.. and the clang equivalent is actually the flag displayed in the error msg `-Wshadow-uncaptured-local` [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wshadow-uncaptured-local) ! Or could also do your suggestion "install a true GCC".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time ago, GCC was the default compiler on MacOS, then Apple decided to switch to clang as default. Suppose they linked GCC to clang to avoid people wondering why the compiler disappeared (well, more reasonable: not to break any build systems...). Good idea? At least leading to confusion where incompatibilities come into play...

> "How to fix?"

Install a true GCC on your system, replacing the symlink to clang.

If you prefer going on with clang (not a bad choice either), drop the flag that apparently is GCC-specific and not supported by clang (you can replace it with clang's equivalent, see [vpetrigo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5102289/vpetrigo)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52342818/1312382)).

You even might adapt your makefile to be compatible with both: [Get](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2741747/1312382) the compiler's version string, check if the string returned [contains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2741747/1312382) "gcc" or "clang" and then add the appropriate compiler flags conditionally.

Comment: The last paragraph is **not** a good idea. It hard-codes assumptions that will be wrong in a few years if not months. Instead, perform a configure-time (or equivalent) **test** to determine if the compiler supports the warning you want, and only enable it if it's supported.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that `clang` uses quite different flag naming: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wshadow-uncaptured-local

It should be `-Wshadow-uncaptured-local` rather than `-Wshadow=compatible-local`.