# How do I validate a GNU Makefile parameter exists in a string

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to get this rule to work. Its totally blowing up my whole Makefile.

It **should** validate that the value for `version` the user passed exists in the `PYVERSION` variable.

The **actual** behavior is mixed because I've tried so many different things. I'm no GNU expert so I've tried `${version}` and `$(version)` and `$version` and the same things for `PYVERSION`. The current version I've posted here *always* goes to the else block, not matter the `version` input.

```
PYVERSIONS := "3.5 3.6 3.7 3.8"

.PHONY: venv
venv:
    if test $(findstring ${version}, $(PYVERSIONS)); then
        /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/${version}/bin/python3 -m venv venv
    else
        $(error Bad python version given (${version}) project only supports ${PYVERSIONS})
    fi;
```

- calling it like `make venv version=3.5` should successfully execute the `if` block and create the `venv`.
- calling it like `make venv version=2.7` should raise the error message in the else block.

I was trying to follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741708/makefile-contains-string)

### Update

With help from @Beta, this is the final solution I got to work.

```py
PYVERSIONS := "3.6 3.7 3.8"
PYPATH := /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions

.PHONY: venv
venv:
    @if test $(findstring ${version}, $(PYVERSIONS)) ; \
    then \
      echo "Creating virtual environment for python ${version}"; \
      $(PYPATH)/${version}/bin/python3 -m venv venv; \
    else \
      echo "Unsupported python version (${version}). Project supports $(PYVERSIONS)"; \
    fi
```

Comment: Your question should remain strictly a question. If you want to post an answer of your own, you are welcome to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing shell syntax with Make syntax.

If you want to handle this with a *shell* conditional, you must put the whole thing on one line in the recipe (since each line executes in its own subshell):

```
venv:
    if test $(findstring ${version}, $(PYVERSIONS)) ; then echo $(version)/bin/python3 venv; else  echo bad version $(version); fi
```

or you can wrap the line by means of backslashes:

```
venv:
    if test $(findstring ${version}, $(PYVERSIONS)) ; \
  then \
   echo $(version)/bin/python3 venv; \
  else \
   echo bad version $(version); \
  fi
```

(Note that there is only one TAB, in front of `if`.)

If you want to use a *Make* conditional within the rule:

```
venv:
ifeq ($(findstring ${version}, $(PYVERSIONS)),)
    echo bad version $(version);
else
    echo echo $(version)/bin/python3 venv;
endif
```

If you want to use the Maker `error` command, you have a problem. Make will evaluate the conditional before executing any rule, so if you use `error`, then if no valid version number is given, Make will throw the error *even if `venv` was not the target.* It is possible to use `error`, but it's a pain, so you must first decide whether the effect is worth the price.

Comment: You rock @Beta. I couldn't get your solution to work for a while because I didn't read the last part :/ and still tried to use the Make `error`. Updating my question with the full solution.

Answer (score 3):

Actually disagree with @Beta here. Since the answer is known before you even start executing the recipe, `$(error …)` is the clear way to go.

Now, *make* stores the entire recipe as a single recursively expanded variable. When *make* decides to build *venv* (for instance, you type `make venv`), it will expand the entire recipe, before passing each resulting line one-by-one to fresh instances of the shell.

Thing is, when *make* expands your recipe,
it *always* expands `$(error Bad python version given …)`, and *make* stops even before calling the shell.

How do we get around this?

```
PYVERSIONS := 3.6 3.7 3.8
PYPATH := /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions

pyversion = $(or $(filter ${version},${PYVERSION}),$(error $$version [${version}] must be exactly one of ${PYVERSIONS}))

.PHONY: venv
venv:
    echo "Creating virtual environment for python ${version}"
    $(PYPATH)/${pyversion}/bin/python3 -m venv venv
```

So,

- You type `make venv`
- *Make* expands the recipe
- *Make* expands `pyversion`

  - *Make* expands `$(filter ${version},3.6 3.7 3.8)`

    - If you have not set *version* on the command-line or environment to one of the three blessed strings,
      *make* stops there and then with a helpful message **NICE**
    - OTOH if it has been set appropritely, *make* is happy and starts executing the recipe

Other nice characteristics:

- No shell syntax
- The exit code of *python3* is returned to *make* (a big hole in your original recipe imho).

Things always look better in *make* rather than the shell.

Comment: I really like this. Question for you, does make only expand `pyversion` if the `venv` recipe is called? My make-less brain sees this as a line by line execution so I would expect this to throw an error when I run `make other-thing` and there is no version set. I did test it and it works perfectly, it somehow knows to ignore pyversion when running other recipie/rules.

Comment: Yes that is correct. The recipe is only expanded just before _make_ wants to execute it. This is true of all recipes. In the makefile sketched above, the check is carried out every time `${pyversion}` is expanded, and is never carried out if `${pyversion}` is not used. And just to emphasize, the check is done without bothering the shell.